# Выборка с MySQL c заменой символов (;)

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Всем привет, помогите.
В базе MySQL есть столбец с такими данными:

| user_agent |
| --- |
| Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36 |

Импортируя его в CSV, делит на несколько столбцов. **(Вариант 1)**

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0 | Win64 | x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36 |

Хочу что бы было вот так:  **(Вариант 2)**

| user_agent |
| --- |
| Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0: Win64: x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36 |

Используя код

```
SELECT *, REPLACE (`user_agent`, ';', ' :') FROM ...
```

в файл импортирует сначала **Вариант 1**, а в конце всей таблицы **Вариант 2**.
Как иначе можно сделать что бы импортировало только **Вариант 2**?

MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33

Comment: во-первых, если писать в csv правильно, через fputscsv(), то ничего не будет делить. во-вторых, очевидно чето если не писать select * а перечислить все поля поименно, то будет только один раз.

Comment: Их много, и там сливается две таблицы в одну.

Comment: Звезду из запроса удалите, да... экспортируйте ТОЛЬКО нужные поля и выражения.

Comment: *её делит на несколько столбцов.* Кто делит-то? Небось, в Эксель загружаете? Ну так используйте мастер экспорта данных, укажите какой-нить дикий разделитель, которого в файле нет, и будет всё в шоколаде само по себе. А если  лениться и делать всё по дефолту - так обязательно что-то пойдёт не так.

Comment: Да хоть 10 таблиц. Тупо перечислить поля  было бы быстрее чем писать сюда свой вопрос. Уже бы все работало

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое.